# How to handle callback return response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In my REST POST/PUT request I will send callback url with additional data
Once backend server responded with success or failure, i will get response to my callback url.
How can see what response in callback url in Jmeter. Based on response I process further

Answer (score 0):

If this is a 3rd-party URL there is no possibility to intercept the request from your backend to this callback URL with JMeter

If you can change the callback URL to an arbitrary value you can use i.e. [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server) as the callback URL, this way your backend will send the request to JMeter instead of the 3rd-party URL so you will be able to get the status and eventually re-send the request to the callback URL so it won't be lost.

If this is not possible you can investigate where the information about the job status is stored, if it can be found in a log file you can use [OS Process Sampler or SSH Command sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) to get it, if it's in the database - you can retrieve it using [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html), etc.